# Sorting SQL results in the query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT A.*, 
       B.surname, 
       B.name, 
       C.url_address, 
       (SELECT Concat(file_path, '/', file_name) AS image 
        FROM   psuploadedfiles B 
        WHERE  enum = 3 
               AND category = A.id_user 
        ORDER  BY number ASC 
        LIMIT  1) AS image2, 
       (SELECT Concat(file_path, '/', file_name) AS image 
        FROM   psuploadedfiles B 
        WHERE  enum = 3 
               AND category = A.post_id 
        ORDER  BY number ASC 
        LIMIT  1) AS image 
FROM   psposts A 
       LEFT JOIN psuserdetails B 
              ON B.id_user = A.id_user 
       LEFT JOIN psuser C 
              ON C.id_user = A.id_user 
WHERE  A.enable = '1' 
       AND ( A.id_user = 21 
              OR ( A.id_user = '7' 
                    OR A.id_user = '1' 
                    OR A.id_user = '5' ) ) 
ORDER  BY date DESC 
LIMIT  0, 25;
```

In the *psPosts* table, I have a *subscriptions_date* column (containing a date in yyyy-mm-dd format) where *subscriptions_date* is date until when the post will be promoted.

How can I sort the results in such a way that there are posts at the top containing *subscriptions_date* current or future date (i.e. promoted), and underneath the other posts?

Comment: Please post current results and desired result which help *show* and not *tell* your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like...

```
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN A.subscriptions_date >= NOW() THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
    date
```

The first sort criteria splits data into two groups, with current or future subscriptions in first place. Within each group, data is then sorted by `date`.